Wagmi useWatchContractEvent no logs
I'm utilising the Coinbase Wallet with "wagmi": "^2.10.2", in "react": "18.2.0" app. All in all everything works, but when i tried to listen for emitted events the logs are not showing anything.
Here is the code:
wagmi.ts
import { http, createConfig } from 'wagmi';
import { base } from 'wagmi/chains';
import { coinbaseWallet } from 'wagmi/connectors';

export const config = createConfig({
  chains: [base],
  connectors: [coinbaseWallet({ appName: 'appName', preference: 'smartWalletOnly' })],
  ssr: true,
  transports: {
    [base.id]: http()
  }
});

declare module 'wagmi' {
  interface Register {
    config: typeof config;
  }
}

SomeComponent.tsx
  ...
  useWatchContractEvent({
    ...contractAbiAndAddress,
    eventName: 'Transfer',
    onLogs(logs) {
      console.log('New logs!', logs);
    }
  });
  ...

Expected: console.log('New logs!', logs); to log something.
Actual: Nothing happens.
NOTE: Everything apart from that hook works...

You need to use some third-party RPC provider (like Alchemy) in the transports object because RPCs that wagmi is using by-default aren’t allowing the calls to listen to the events, and that’s why, it would throw 403 error.
And, you also need to add the syncConnectedChain field (and mark its value as true) inside the createConfig of your wagmi.ts file:
export const config = createConfig({
  chains: [base],
  connectors: [coinbaseWallet({ appName: 'appName', preference: 'smartWalletOnly' })],
  ssr: true,
  syncConnectedChain: true,
  transports: {
    [base.id]: http(`https://base-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/${process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY}`),
  }
});

NOTE: When we don't use an explicit RPC url and just use http() inside the transports object, then the value of syncConnectedChain defaults to true, but as we need to use some third party RPC provider url explicitly, that's why we need to mark the syncConnectedChain value as true.
P.S., You can also check for various RPCs listed on Chainlist, as publicnode.com one seems to be working fine too in case of most of the networks.

Why? What is the need for this, that is what I am trying to understand.

And still doesn't log anything.

Actually, some RPCs aren’t allowing the calls to listen events. That’s why, it’s throwing 403 error. You can also check for various RPCs listed on Chainlist. publicnode.com one seems to be working fine too in case of most of the networks.

Sorry, syncConnectedChain: true needs to be added in the createConfig instead. I've revised my answer and added some supporting explanation. Please check.

if you are using walletconnect... it works:
export const config = defaultWagmiConfig({
  chains,
  projectId,
  metadata,
  ssr: true,
  storage: createStorage({
    storage: cookieStorage,
  }),
  transports: {
    [mainnet.id]: http("https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/...apiKey"),
    [sepolia.id]: http("https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/...apiKey"),
  },
});

